# Ruby recursion error

Tags: ruby

Does anyone know why this code:

```
sum=0
def get_sum n
    return sum if n<1
    sum=sum+n
    get_sum(n-1)
end 

get_sum 10
```

gives me this?

```
rb:3:in `get_sum': undefined local variable or method `sum' for main:Object (NameError)
from 1.rb:8:in `<main>'
```

The code makes perfectly sense, and you can understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal variables declared outside a function are *not* accessible inside the function.

You could prefix `sum` with `$` to make it a global variable (not usually a good idea.)

```
$sum=0
def get_sum n
    return $sum if n<1
    $sum=$sum+n
    get_sum(n-1)
end 

get_sum 10
#= 55
```

If you have a real test case where you want to do this, I can suggest a suitable approach if you want.

Comment: If you're playing around with functional Ruby, you should use functions, not methods. Or more precisely: blocks.

Comment: Also, mutable variables and functional programming are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a global variable, another method using recursion would be like this (limited by stack depth, I guess):

```
def get_sum(n)
  return n if n < 1
  n + get_sum(n - 1)
end

sum = get_sum(10)
```

If you ever use a Ruby implementation that offers tail call optimization (I don't know of any implementations that do), [ProGNOMmers's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786771/ruby-recursion-error/15786882#15786882) would be a bit nicer on the stack, but as is a quick test has both exceeding the maximum stack level around `n = 9000` or so. Not that you should be recursing 9000 times or anything.

Answer (score 1):

As @Dogbert wrote, *normal variables declared outside a function are not accessible inside
the function*.

This is an approach which doesn't use global variables (which are not suited for recursion):

```
def get_sum(n, sum = 0)
    return sum if n<1
    get_sum(n-1, sum+n)
end 

get_sum(10) #=> 55
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized the variable `sum` before using it.

You can totally avoid using that variable, since it does nothing:

```
def get_sum n
    return 0 if n<1
    get_sum(n-1) + n
end 

get_sum 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try this :

```
def get_sum n
    return n if n == 0
    return n + get_sum(n-1)
end
```

In this version you don't need to instanciate any global variable ( which is not a good idea ), and you actually perform a regressive sum :)

Comment: Testing for `n==0` is not adequate. What will your code do if it receives -1? Use `<` or `<=`.

Comment: That wasn't really the point I was discussing. Nevertheless, if you want your code to accept negative integers then you probably need a particular case where n<0 is taken into account. Otherwise it just don't make any sense to pretend that sum ( -3) = -3